# PosgreasSQL index is not applied when select?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my database, I created a index

```
CREATE INDEX meeting_name_idx ON swoosh.meeting (meeting_name varchar_pattern_ops);
```

So based on the index that I have for table "meeting", if I do:

```
Explain SELECT meeting_name FROM meeting WHERE meeting_name like 'Pro%';
```

I would get

```
index only scan using meeting_name_idx on meeting
```

But if I changed the `%` in this case, and I do

```
Explain SELECT meeting_name FROM meeting WHERE meeting_name like '%Pro';
```

The result would be a sequential scan, why is that?

Comment: When we use `LIKE` operator and the first character in the search string is a wildcard character (`%` or `_`), the sql optimizer will be forced to do a table/index scan. In Postgresql, you may consider to enable `pg_trgm`. See https://scoutapm.com/blog/how-to-make-text-searches-in-postgresql-faster-with-trigram-similarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a default index on the `meeting_name` text column, it will create a B-tree data structure.  This B-tree inherently only allows for lookups starting at the very beginning of the meeting name, not from some arbitrary location in the string.  So the following `WHERE` clauses can leverage the index:

```sql
WHERE meeting_name = 'Professional SQL Users'
WHERE meeting_name = 'Pro%'
```

The following *cannot* use the index:

```sql
WHERE meeting_name LIKE '%Pro%';
```

Note that Postgres actually *could* still use the index even for the above, but it would have to do a full index scan, along with doing many lookups in the clustered index.  Most likely, Postgres would prefer to just scan the original table in this case and avoid the index.